# Are we somehow misusing CR.Meta? (what's off-topic on meta?)

Tags: discussion, meta

Don't get me wrong, I love the fact that this site is far less, uh, *stuck-up* (in a good way?) than SO/MSO can be (despite the [occasional craziness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon)). Maybe it's because we're short of a moderator, but I feel like some meta-discussions (and sometimes even on the main site) would get the involved people (including myself) a little slap if it were posted on MSO.

Are we underusing *Chat* and abusing comments? Or *hey, it's meta, relax bud, that's fine*?

Basically, where do laid-back, off-topic discussions really belong? Or should we be keeping it all to ourselves? I guess *some* of these comments could be somewhat entertaining to passers-by, but at the same time they might make our community look smaller than it really is... and people coming here from SO/MSO might frown at those.

Where's the line drawn between *bringing your humor* and *turning meta into a big chatroom*?

<sub>sorry to be such a party-breaker :)</sub>

Comment: Dude, chill. :-) Seriously though, if you're also referring to [this question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/971/down-voting-discussion), then we can clean up those comments.  I may add an answer here later as well.

Comment: I guess if no moderator stepped in and cleaned it up, it's fine then. But then moderators should have better things to do than clean up after meta's most [hyper]active users, ..with or without a COD (uh, that's *Call of Duty* right?), so the line is a little blurry. Actually what planted the seed was [this edit](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/33968/revisions).

Comment: Right.  As long as they're not getting offensive, it should be okay.  Even if someone flags them, only a moderator can review those flags.

Comment: I think the opinions so far expressed on this page are slightly biased :)

Comment: Where have all the Cowboys gone?

Comment: that sounds really off-topic, but I mean where are the Meta-riders, or the Dedicated Code Reviewers, or the people that backed the site before it went beta?

Comment: Take a look: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/users

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The people at SO are drinking from a firehose.  They *have to* be intolerant of fluff.  Letting 500 people get chatty at once in meta would drown all of the signal out.  Letting 5 people get chatty in meta makes it feel friendly.

MSO is not a good measuring stick for CR.Meta.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is okay to let humor out in our posts to let people know that we aren't all just Code Police that stick to the rules and nothing but the rules.

on some posts on Meta, the comments are going to be long because of the question or answer, and it's totally on-topic.

I guess the real question we should be asking is, **what is Off-Topic for Meta?**

this answer would help us decide if our comments to questions is out of line and getting `"off-topic"`.

Comment: I wouldn't say that adding comments could actually make a question off-topic.  In the event that it gets chatty to the point where it in no way relates to the question, then they can be removed.  Topic-wise, there's much flexibility on any Meta site.  The question just has to relate to the specific site and cannot be one that belongs on the main site.

Comment: I meant that we will know if the comments are going off topic or not.